# mongodb update multiple Array elements using db.update()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

I compiled 2 update queries by referring to related stackoverflow answers, however, it doesn't seem to work, query updates all elements while only elements matching the criteria are expected to update.

Document:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 259,
    "members": [
      {
        "email": "test1@gmail.com",
        "added_by": "javapedia.net",
        "status": "pending"
      },
      {
        "email": "test2@gmail.com",
        "added_by": "javapedia.net",
        "status": "pending"
      },
      {
        "email": "test3@gmail.com",
        "status": "pending"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Query1: Using elemMatch operator,  mongodb playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/4cNgWJse86W

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 259,
  "members": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "email": {
        "$in": [
          "test3@gmail.com",
          "test4@gmail.com"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "$set": {
    "members.$[].status": "active"
  }
},
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Query2: using $in, mongodb playground : https://mongoplayground.net/p/tNu395B2RFx

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 259,
  "members.email": {
    "$in": [
      "test3@gmail.com",
      "test4@gmail.com"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "$set": {
    "members.$[].status": "active"
  }
},
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Expected result: only one element with test3@gmail.com status should be updated to active.

Actual result: both queries update all records.

Comment: also, include a sample document, `$elemMatch` looks rare to me

Comment: yyou could do `"members.email":{$in..."`

Comment: @turivishal, I may need to update multiple docs, in the example, I just covered only one doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Is this what you're looking for?](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CtXEEr385Ef)

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 259,  
},
{
  "$set": {
    "members.$[el].status": "active"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "el.email": {
        $in: [
          "test3@gmail.com",
          "test4@gmail.com"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

- You can put the initial conditions back if needed, I just keep this short (and to me they make no sense).
- `multi:true` isn't needed for one document
- Maybe better semantically to use `updateOne()`